# WebSocket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to create a web socket for a django application using django-channels. I have changed django to use a `ASGI` server interface instead of the default `WSGI` and I have defined the following channel layers:

*settings.py*

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': { 
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'rest.routing.application',
    }
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'rest.routing.application'
```

*asgi.py*

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rest.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

*routing.py*

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    "websocket": URLRouter([
            url(r"^receive/$", websocket_receive),
            url(r"^connect/$", websocket_connect),
        ])
})
```

*consumers.py*

```
def websocket_connect(self, event):
    self.send({
        "type": "websocket.accept",
    })
```

The problem is that when I try to test it

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/connect/");
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");
}
```

I keep getting

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/connect/' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send'
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\autobahn\websocket\protocol.py:2800:processHandshake
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\txaio\tx.py:429:as_future
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\daphne\ws_protocol.py:77:onConnect
--- <exception caught here> ---
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py:186:create_application
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py:41:__call__
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py:58:__call__
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py:144:__call__
C:.......\consumers.py:28:websocket_connect
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: where are your handlers `websocket_receive` etc. these need to be classes that subclass WebsocketConsumer of AsyncWebsocketConsumer etc.  Not free standing methods.